# Using WPF StoryBoard Forward and Reverse

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I need help in the Storyboard Seek. The following code is not working:

```
Storyboard StoryBoard;

public void Reverse()
            {
                StoryBoard.Pause(this);

                TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0);
                ts.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                StoryBoard.Seek(this, ts, TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
            }

public void Forward()
            {
                StoryBoard.Pause(this);

                TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0);
                ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                StoryBoard.Seek(this, ts, TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
            }
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You should really be more precise than "is not working". What errors do you get? What would you expect to happen and what happens instead? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okay. It is not throwing any error. It always go to the first clip.

Answer (score 2):

**For Reverse:**

```
TimeSpan CurrentTime = (TimeSpan) StoryBoard.CurrentTime;
TimeSpan SubtractTime = CurrentTime.Subtract(new TimeSpan(FrameRate * (long)Math.Pow(10,4)));
StoryBoard.Seek(SubtractTime, TimeSeekOrigin.Duration);
```

**For Forward:**

```
TimeSpan CurrentTime = (TimeSpan) StoryBoard.CurrentTime;
TimeSpan AddTime = CurrentTime.Add(new TimeSpan(FrameRate * (long)Math.Pow(10,4)));
StoryBoard.Seek(AddTime, TimeSeekOrigin.Duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do this

```
 Storyboard anime = (Storyboard)FindResource("Storyboard1");
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0);
        anime.Seek(ts);
        anime.Stop();
```